# What kind of design to use for nested options?

Tags: mobile, android

I have this kind of structure.

At the top I have 2 options,
Depending on which, I have 2 or 3 options,
Below them I have single layout.

This options are changeable. I want user to select from options and see actual layout. I want those options be changeable too.

I think I need something like nested tabs. What's the proper way to present this stuff on android?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more details? What is being nested? Simple objects, conditional form elements? If you have a more fleshed out mock, this will help generate more specific answers.

Answer (score 3):

**Alternating backgrounds** can show the context of each level of nesting.

**Indenting for the new level of nesting** also can help. If the level of nesting is very deep (depending on your screen size) you may need to limit the indentation.

Here is an example with a hypothetical deeply-nested if conditions. Notice on the deepest level of nesting, the indentation has been reduced to save screen real estate.

[image]